# MediaWiki won't redirect to page after successful login

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, mediawiki

I'm setting up a private wiki under a subdomain of a domain my company uses for wikis on AWS.  I just purchased the MediaWiki instance from the AWS marketplace and have been working to just get the wiki up and running including setting up the admin account passwords, installing a Let's Encrypt cert for HTTPS, and disabling access to anonymous users.  I was testing to verify that this works when I ran into an issue: upon successful login, a blank "Log in" page is shown instead of redirecting to the original destination.

So first I go to `https://private.example.com/index.php/Main_Page` and get a "Login required" page with a link to log in.  This is expected.

When I click on the link, I get sent to `https://private.example.com/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&returnto=Main+Page&returntoquery=` with the title "Log in" and the log in form, which looks good so far.

However when I enter in the admin username and password and submit, I expect to be redirected back to `https://private.example.com/index.php/Main_Page` with the content visible, but instead I get redirected to `https://private.example.com/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&returnto=Main+Page` with the title "Log in" and no body.  I've tried this on a different browser to see if it is some sort of caching issue, but I get the same results there too.

Since I've done almost nothing, I don't know what I could have done to cause this.  Is there a configuration that I either failed to setup correctly or perhaps corrupted that might cause this?  Could it be related to the wiki having a subdomain URL?

Comment: Does navigating to the URL `https://private.example.com/index.php/Main_Page` after login do anything?

Comment: @astonearachnid Yes, it loads that page normally with all the expected content.

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that the logs seem to indicate that the response from the login POST is 200.  Shouldn't it be 302?

`"POST /index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&returnto=Main+Page HTTP/1.1" 200 15146 "https://private.example.com/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&returnto=Main+Page&returntoquery=" "Mozilla/5....`

Comment: On my wiki it appears that I get a `302` on my login POST request (the same request as referenced in your comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be caused by the `$wgServer` variable in `LocalSettings.php` (likely located at `/var/www/mediawiki/LocalSettings.php`) not being set (or set properly). I.e. the redirect won't work if it's empty, e.g.:

```
$wgServer = "";
```

So in your case it would need to be set like this:

```
$wgServer = "https://private.example.com";
```

I.e. the scheme and domain of your site.